# cronjob executing a php file

Tags: php, cron, centos7

So I have a php file that executes each time it you reload it in the web browser. It uses PHPMailer, to send mail based on criteria in my db. I was attempting to use a cronjob to execute the file which I thought would basically do the same as reloading the page. The php file that I need to run in the cronjob is `test.php`, and its path is `/var/www/html/mailer/test.php`.

My cronjob is:
`1 * * * * root /var/www/html/mailer/test.php >> /var/www/html/mailer/cron_status.log`

and it should be throwing errors into that `cron_status.log` file, but its empty. I realize that this is firing every minute, but I'm just doing it to test the cronjob, and I really need to set it to 24hrs. With no error output, and no emails landing where they should be, I don't think I've properly setup my cronjob. This is my first time ever trying this. This is on a centos 7 droplet, and I've followed the tutorial from digital ocean with no success.

Comment: from the command line does running `php /var/www/html/mailer/test.php` work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to see the php file to be sure, but you probably need to change it to this:

```
1 * * * * php /var/www/html/mailer/test.php >> /var/www/html/mailer/cron_status.log
```

Comment: I leave out the `root` ?

Comment: Would I need to have an execute function or something on php file? There isn't really a execute function on the page, its just fired when the page is reloaded in the browser. and with that edit you suggested, it's still not working.

Comment: Thats what the "php" is for at the beginning.  That is what executes the file.

Comment: Yes, you should not need "root".  If you want to execute the script as the root user, then you should edit root's crontab (ie sudo crontab -e).

Comment: Try running it from a command line to trouble shoot, that is way easier then waiting from cron...

Comment: From a command-line a type: `php /var/www/html/mailer/test.php` and see what happens

Comment: Hey Evan, yeah you were right. adding in the `php` solved my problem. Thank you.